# What's The main difference between the two types of the following arrays?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is differences between Multidimensional array and Array of Arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c)
>   [What's the difference between arrays of arrays and multidimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177615/whats-the-difference-between-arrays-of-arrays-and-multidimensional-arrays)

```
TYPE [,] ARRAY_NAME;
TYPE [][] ARRAY_NAME;
```

I can't differ between them , the first type declare an array of tow dimensional and the second also does the same thing As I think ?

Comment: Better to search the question first. Show some effort man.

Answer (score 1):

- TYPE [,] ARRAY_NAME; [is a multi dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4)
- TYPE [][] ARRAY_NAME; [is a jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca)

Answer (score 0):

[,] is multidimensional array

[][] is jagged array

http://www.dotnetperls.com/jagged-array