# Appending subarray of multidimensional array to PHP associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can portions of multidimensional arrays be added to an existing two-dimensional (associative)
array?

For example, for an existing associative array with the following elements:

```
$builder = array();
$builder['builder_id'] =        $source['id'];
$builder['builder_name'] =      $source['name'];
$builder['builder_address'] =   $source['address'];
```

how can portions of the following multidimensional array:

```
$selection[$category['category_name']]['item_name'] = $category_general['item_name'];
$selection[$category['category_name']]['item_source'] = $category_general['item_source'];
$selection[$category['category_name']]['item_image'] = $category_general['item_image'];
```

be appended to create the following structure:

```
$builder['builder_id']
$builder['builder_name']
$builder['builder_address']
$builder['category_name']
$builder['category_name']['item_name']
$builder['category_name']['item_source']
$builder['category_name']['item_image']
```

Assignments like this didn't work:

```
$builder['category_name'] = $selection[$category['category_name']];
$builder['category_name'] = $selection[$category['category_name']][];
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

*edit:

@symcbean you are correct. assignment failed due to null element in array being assigned.

@Snowsickle thanks for tip which identified source of problem noted.*

Comment: PHP arrays are not multi-dimensional - they are nested.

Comment: can you clarify the difference between nested and multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Is google down *again*? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177615/whats-the-difference-between-arrays-of-arrays-and-multidimensional-arrays for starters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first assignment should work.

```
$builder['category_name'] = $selection[$category['category_name']];
```

will assign all values contained in the array `$selection[$category['category_name']]` to the array `$builder['category_name']`.

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3635f282f3d2fa4927b9c9a3da25d570bab5f6e)

Comment: PHP Error received when using this assignment method:  
  
`A PHP Error was encountered`  
`Severity: Notice`  
`Message: Undefined index: Residential & Commercial`  
`Filename: controllers/cron.php`  
`Line Number: 238`

Comment: Snowsickle is correct. If you get that error then the assignment you've shown in the second block of code in your question will fail too - and it the reason it fails is due to the contents of the $category array - not the method for combining the arrays.

Comment: @pseudo, please so a [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) of both the $selection and $builder arrays and edit your question with the result.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment should work.. but if you need an alternative method:

```
foreach($selection[$category['category_name']] as $key => $value)
{
    $builder['category_name'][$key] = $value;
}
```

But once again, assignment with arrays has always worked for me.